# Getting Valgrind to detect memory leaks from C++ program called by Python Script:

Tags: python, c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

If a C++ program is called by a python script, how do you get Valgrind to check leaks in the C++ program and not just in the script? For example, if `leak.cc` contains the following code

```
int main() {
    int* p = new int;
}
```

and is compiled into `a.out`, and `call_aout.py` contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["./a.out"])
```

then running valgrind via

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full -v ./call_aout.py
```

will not detect the memory leak in `leak.cc`, but calling it via

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full -v ./a.out
```

will detect it.

Comment: Do you make `valgrind` track new, forked processes, too?

Comment: @KerrekSB: `valgrind` always follows forks, but he needs it to follow an `exec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use:

```
  --trace-children=yes
```

in your valgrind command line.  Alternatively if you don't care about the python script all you can launch your subprocess with `valgrind` from within the script:

```
subprocess.call("valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full -v ./a.out")
```